# Morpheme help: How many morphemes does the word "dost" (Shakespeare) have?

Tags: morphology

How many morphemes does the word "dost" (Shakespeare) have? How many morphemes does the word "thy" have? How many morphemes does the word "thou" have? Are "and", "if", "of", "a", "but", and "in" considered morphemes?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! In the future, please make sure to ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 3):

Two.  "Do" is a root word.  "[st](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-st)" is a suffix, like 's' or 'es'.

Comment: The interesting question is whether "do" (as in "I do") contains one or two morphemes. Some analyses would give it a null inflection morpheme, to be parallel with "dost". The infinitive "do" would not contain this.

Comment: Similar to my point about 'thy'.

Comment: Cool point, too.  Thanks for the reading, Barrie.  I'm here to learn, and you're helping me to do so. :)

Answer (score 3):

*Thy* is a reduced form of *thine*, which is the genitive of *thou*. It could therefore be argued that *thine*, at least, consists of two morphemes, *thou* and its inflectional ending. Whether such an analysis extends to *thy* would no doubt serve to keep grammarians amused on many a long winter evening.

*And, if, of, a, but* and *in* are all morphemes.